# How to expand number ranges in specific pattern in file using vim script

Tags: vi, vim

While search the list, there are threads showing how to expand a visual block of number range. But my requirement is different.

While cleaning LaTeX files, I used to get patterns like `\cite{1}-\cite{10}` which should be changed to `\cite{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`. Is there a way to make this cleaning easier, so that vim script takes care of the cleaning using `s///gec`.

For example, I had added several cleaning lines with `s///gec` and `s///ge` in one function (say `BasicClean()`) which will be executed by hitting `<F5>` key on visual mode. I need to add the new function (say `ExpandCite()`) to this function.

For example,

```
function! BasicClean()
  " add a new function ExpandCite() for expanding \cite{1}-\cite{10}
  call ExpandCite()
  s/},\s*\\cite{/,/gec
  " ...
endfunc
```

How can I write the `ExpandCite()` function to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\=` followed by an expression in your substitute command to do more complex replacements.

```
:%s/\\cite{\(\d\+\)}-\\cite{\(\d\+\)}/\='\cite{'.join(range(submatch(1),submatch(2)),',').'}'/ge
```

For more help see:

```
:h :s\=
:h submatch(
:h range(
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. It worked as per my expectations and it was very simple. I did not even think it can be done this much easier.